Wordpress: community-new/page/2/ not found
So basically, I created a custom post with Advanced Custom Fields for WordPress that includes pagination. The pagination renders even and adequately shows the pagination button, but when I navigate to the second page, it goes to /community-news/page/2/, which leads to a 404  error. The main page is /community-news. I have had added the custom_disable_redirect_canonical function in my function.php as required but still it doesn't work. I also changed the permalink to Custom structure /community-news/page/%pagename%/ but nothing
I am using the shortcode to add the PHP function to my page and the function is as follows

function display_all_news() {
    // Query all news posts
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'community-news',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5, // Adjust as needed
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $output = '';


    // Check if there are any news posts exists
    if ($query->have_posts()) {

         // Start card container
        $output .= '<div class="card-container">';

        
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $news_title = get_the_title();
            $news_featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'large'); 
            $news_description = get_the_excerpt();
            $news_createdAt = get_the_date('F j, Y', $post_id); 
            $author_name = get_the_author(); 
            $news_link = get_field('post_link', $post_id); 
            
        

            // Build HTML output for each community post
            $output .= '<div class="card">';

            $output .= '<figure class="card-image">';
            if ($news_featured_image) {
                $output .= '<img src="' . esc_url($news_featured_image) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($news_title) . '" />';
            }
            $output .= '</figure>';
            $output .= '<div class="card-content">';
                        $output .= '<span class="author">Author: ' . $author_name . '</span>';
            $output .= '<span class="date">Posted on: ' . $news_createdAt . '</span>';
            $output .= '<h2>' . esc_html($news_title) . '</h2>';
            $output .= '<p>' . esc_html(shorten_post($news_description)) . '</p>';

            //button
            $output .= '<div class="btn-container">';
            // button tag
            $output .= '<a class="btn" href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="see-more">See More</a>';
            $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '</div>';

            $output .= '</div>';

        }

        $output .= '</div>';

        // Reset post data
        wp_reset_postdata();

          // Pagination Links
        $output .= '<div class="pagination-links">';
        $output .= paginate_links( array(
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current' => $paged,
            'prev_text' => __( 'Previous Page', 'textdomain' ),
            'next_text' => __( 'Next Page', 'textdomain' ),
        ) );
        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;
    }
    

    return 'No News posts found.';
}



add_shortcode('all_news', 'display_all_news');


If you’re on a static homepage or any other static page, WordPress uses the query var page, not paged. If you’re on an archive page or the blog page, WordPress uses paged. So get_query_var('paged') is used on archive pages, category pages, and the blog page. It retrieves the current page number of a paginated list, and get_query_var('page')  is used on single pages and posts. It retrieves the page number of a paginated post or static front page. Try replacing 'paged' with 'page' in your get_query_var.
